# C++ IPv6 string representation into boost::multiprecision::uint128_t

Tags: c++, boost

I need to convert IPv6 string address into boost::multiprecision::uint128_t
For IPv4 I used the following algorithm:

```
uint32_t byte1 = 0, byte2 = 0, byte3 = 0, byte4 = 0;
sscanf(ipAddress, "%3d.%3d.%3d.%3d", &byte1, &byte2, &byte3, &byte4);
uint32_t ip = (byte1 << 24) | (byte2 << 16) | (byte3 << 8) | (byte4);
```

How can I do like this for IPv6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address):

[image]

Also using Boost Asio's `address_v6` implementation instead of a 1970-era parsing:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e8dad455c74d5d1)**

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/address_v6.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

using boost::asio::ip::address_v6;
using boost::multiprecision::int128_t;

int main() {
    auto v6 = address_v6::from_string("2001:0DBB:AC10:FE01::");

    int128_t val {};
    for (uint8_t b : v6.to_bytes())
        (val <<= 8) |= b;

    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << val << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
0x20010dbbac10fe010000000000000000
```